# button keyboard focus issues

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

How would one prevent the little dotted square that appears on a button when it has the keyboard focus in a dialog.  (w/ apologies for the technical jargon). At one point I hacked together a solution by subclassing a button WindowProc and subverting some windows messages, but wanted to know the correct way.

There's actually a problem with another control in the dialog also involving the keyboard.  This other control is actually also a button, but being used as a group box or panel, not as a functioning button.  But when I hit the tab key in the dialog, this group box "button" comes to the foreground obscuring the static controls on top of it, so I wanted to prevent that.

For both of the above, I tried turning off WS_TABSTOP - didn't help.)

Comment: You could try setting the focus to something else upon WM_SETFOCUS message being received.

Comment: You know I believe that will actually work for the group box button.  It did not work for the normal button however - it prevented the dotted square, but caused other problems (the button in question is actually a pushlike check box with the appearance of a normal button, but stays pushed when "checked".  Its also of type BS_ICON, and I'm drawing a different icon on it depending on the state. so that didn't work correctly when disabling WM_SETFOCUS.

Answer (score 1):

Both of my problems mentioned above were solved by subclassing the WndProcs and returning 0 in response to message 0x128 and discarding it.  Even Spy++ could not identify this message 0x128, and I don't have it in any header.  But its sent to every control in the dialog the first time tab is hit in the dialog.

(I did try BN_SETFOCUS as described above and also WM_SETFOCUS  but it didn't help.)

So if anyone knows where to find what windows message 0x128 is...

Comment: WM_UPDATEUISTATE is the message:

"When a window that draws keyboard cues receives a WM_UPDATEUISTATE message, it typically invalidates itself so that the cues can be redrawn/erased, depending on the new state. "
-http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/03/414317.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to write your own button control instead of using the default Windows one.

Alternatively, you can prevent if from ever getting keyboard focus.

Comment: How do I prevent them from getting keyboard focus - is that not what WS_TABSTOP is for  (I guess all of us have gaps in knowledge no matter what the general proficiency level.)

Comment: The most reliable way is to listen for the BN_SETFOCUS notification from the button, and then set the focus somewhere else.